# Solving $ f'(x) =-\log( f(x) +a ) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lambert-w

Can the solution of $$ f'(x) = -\log( f(x) + a ) $$
with $f(0)=0$ and $a \in (0,1)$ be well approximated by the Lambert W function for $x>0$? It seems that morally this might be the case (by relating $f(x)$ to $f'(x)$ and bootstrapping).

Comment: if you define $y=f(x)$ you have $\frac{dy}{dx}=-log(y+a)$ and then if you make the following transformation $z=y+a$, you end up with $\frac{dz}{dx}=-log(z)$. i'm not completely sure but this o.d.e. seems like it can be solved with direct integration using the Logarithmic integral function, see [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function), although it's a special function and not an explicit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{d}{dx}f(x)=-\ln (f(x)+a) $$
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[f(x)+a\right]=-\ln (f(x)+a) $$
$$ \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(x)+a\right]}{\ln(f(x)+a)}=-1 $$
$$ \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(x)+a\right]}{\ln(f(x)+a)}dx=-1\ dx $$
$$ \int\frac{1}{\ln(f(x)+a)} d\left[f(x)+a\right] =-\int dx $$
$$ \mathrm{li}(f(x)+a)+C_1=-x+C_2 $$
$$ \mathrm{li}(f(x)+a)=-x+C $$
Where $\mathrm{li}(x)$ is the logarithmic integral function.

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave the link here to http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.expi.html#scipy.special.expi